# page not found error in header

Tags: php

The following basic code is working as expected.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "user@123") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
?>
```

What all I need is that instead of mysql_error, page not found 404 error should be returned.
I am looking for the shortest possible code since this is going to be used as load balancer check.

The following does not seem to work. I get a blank page.

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "user@123") or die(header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"));
```

Comment: A blank page would seem quite an appropriate response. Are you getting errors in the log? Have you checked the HTTP header being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following: bearing in mind I am using mysqli instead, the use of mysql_* is highly discouraged.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
} else {

}
```

Are you sure you want to return a 404 though, this is misleading as the resource has been found, I would be returning a 500 error as a server error which would be more appropriate.

For a list of HTTP status codes see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score 1):

[`mysql_connect` will return a false value if the connection was not successful.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

```
$connected = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "user@123");
if (!$connected){
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

Not sure exactly what you are using this code for - but not being able to connect to your database doesn't necessarily mean that the requested page was not found - it could also be an issue with your sql server.

---

As a side note - avoid using the dated mysql_* functions. Using them for new code is highly
[discouraged](http://php.net/mysql_query).
More modern alternatives are available and better maintained.
Consider learning about
[prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)
instead and use either
[PDO or MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).
When used strictly they avoid the tedious and manual escaping part,
thus become heaps easier and as by-product safer to use.
See [a PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC) for starting.

Comment: Since when does `mysql_*` throw exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

Use mysqli or PDO , mysql_* will get depreciated

```
$link =mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "user@123");
if (!$link) {
    header("error.php");
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do a if check and return a 500 error, because if google attempts to see the index page when you fail to connect and throw it back a 404, it will think your site is broken and you will lose ranking and links to that page.

500 will at least show that there is a server problem, but it will be fixed:

```
if(!mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass')){
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Server error');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to check the query time like "show databases" and return 500 error if it takes more than 1 second?